# Camera Intent shows issues in Marshmallow and Nougat

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

My Sample app is working well with the earlier version(before Android M) but getting crash while performing compression after being fetched from internal storage since height and width is coming -1.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);    
int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
```

After doing some research, I come to the conclusion that the the file is getting corrupted at the time of clicking an image in Android N & M, may be since I'm saving the images as a temporary file not sure.

The following code I'm using for clicking an image:

```
public void takePhoto() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File f = null;
    try {
        f = setUpPhotoFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx.getContext(),"com.example.fileprovider", f);
        }
        else{
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        f = null;
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }

    ctx.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}
```

fileprovider.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="images" path="Pictures/AIADMK/"/>
</paths>
```

manifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
</provider>
```

The below is the crash error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AIADMK/IMG_20170428_122804_1986080142.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at helper.ImageHelper.takePhoto(ImageHelper.java:108)
    at helper.ImageHelper$1.onClick(ImageHelper.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1134)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1193)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3231)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4207)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: posted @Raghunandan

Comment: Okay and for lower version the above code@Raghunandan

Comment: i think problem is coming while creating the temporary bitmap so the problem may lies setUpPhotoFile(); in this method so post this first and the complete crash log then we can help

Comment: As i'm saving my clicked image withing the internal storage for example InternalStorage/Pictures/MySample/img200000.jpg then how to specify the name & path within the fileprovide.xml file present under res folder of an app.@Raghunandan

Comment: @PraneshSahu can you post relevant code so that we can run and test?

Comment: @Raghunandan Please find the relevant code what i'm trying recently & gettiing some different issue

Comment: If possible Can you post some link for reference @Raghunandan

Comment: @PraneshSahu https://github.com/raghunandankavi2010/SamplesAndroid/tree/master/StackOverFlowTest. Also check file provider docs.

Comment: Thanks for the git project...@Raghunandan

Answer (score 1):

Add required permissions check before requesting to camera 
and in addition

For Android N,
add this code in onCreate() method of your Application class.

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    }
```

No need to specify provider or path with this.

Note-*Using provider is still the best way to do same task.*

hope it help someone !

Answer (score 0):

check permission for marshmallow

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(yourActivityContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(yourActivityContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 2//requestCode);
            } else {
                selectImage();
            }
```

And override onRequestPermissionsResult of Activity

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 2: //same request code you provided in code above

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   selectImage();

                }


            break;
       }
}
```

Comment: I had given "RunTime Time Permission for M"

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for permission for API 23 and above refer this
   http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/07/29/simple-example-on-using-camera-access-permission-in-android-marshmallow/
2. Check your onActivityResult() is it give you output in bitmap or uri.

3.If you are getting output in uri convert it into bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the latest version of Android because in Android M & N we have to use FileProvider in order to persist the file and for earlier version we can use  Uri.fromFile(f).
I do have to change my fileprovider.xml as listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <external-path name="myexternalimages" path="Pictures/AIADMK" />
</paths>
```